# Java Restful web service: Jax-rs implementation with jersey 2.26 [java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: javax/ws/rs/core/Application.getProperties()]

Tags: maven, jersey-2.0, websphere-8

I am using Maven archetype for my application [jersey-webapp-archetype]. I deployed my application in websphere 8.5.5 and when I run , I am able to hit the application but I am not able to hit the endpoints.
Getting below error:

> Uncaught init() exception created by servlet [Jersey Web Application]
>   in application [ws11]: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError:
>   javax/ws/rs/core/Application.getProperties()Ljava/util/Map;

Pom.xml:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>com.br.audits</groupId>
    <artifactId>wsaudit</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>wsaudit</name>

    <build>
        <finalName>wsaudit</finalName>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.5.1</version>
                <inherited>true</inherited>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey</groupId>
                <artifactId>jersey-bom</artifactId>
                <version>${jersey.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.containers</groupId>
           <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet-core</artifactId> 
            <!-- use the following artifactId if you don't need servlet 2.x compatibility -->
<!--             <artifactId>jersey-container-servlet</artifactId> -->
        </dependency>
        <!-- uncomment this to get JSON support
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.media</groupId>
            <artifactId>jersey-media-json-binding</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        -->

        <dependency>
    <groupId>org.jhades</groupId>
    <artifactId>jhades</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.4</version>
</dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <properties>
        <jersey.version>2.26-b03</jersey.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
</project>
```

***Web.xml:***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!-- This web.xml file is not required when using Servlet 3.0 container, 
    see implementation details http://jersey.java.net/nonav/documentation/latest/jax-rs.html -->
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.glassfish.jersey.servlet.ServletContainer</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
            <param-value>com.br.audits.wsaudit</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.scanning.recursive</param-name>
            <param-value>false</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Jersey Web Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/webapi/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

Comment: WAS 8.5.5 has the JAX-RS API's in it, at version 1.1 I believe. You are using the Jersey that will implement JAX-RS 2.1. The way classloading works in Java you'll be using the WAS version of the JAX-RS apis rather than the Jersey ones. The method in question is not part of the JAX-RS version in WebSphere 8.5.5. Have you tried it in Liberty or with parent last classloading configured?

Comment: Thanks for your response. I tried using parent last class loading and same error. I am not sure about how to use Liberty.